# Fast counting known elements in a list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a solution for one of the Hackerrank problems. The challenge is to count elements in a list, the elements vary from 0 to 99, so it is possible to count them in linear time. Here is what I got:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O3 #-}

module Main where

import Data.STRef
import Data.Foldable
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST

main = do

 line1 <- getLine
 line2 <- getLine

 let
    !ns = map read $ words line2 :: [Int]

    res = runST $ do

        refs <- forM [0..99] $ \i ->
            newSTRef (0 :: Int) 

        traverse_ (\x -> modifySTRef' (refs !! x) (+1) ) ns

        mapM (\ref -> readSTRef ref) refs

 putStrLn . unwords . map show $ res
```

This code works but not fast enough to pass the last test case. Can someone recommend an improvement to it? ([link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/countingsort1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem you have is that you're looking up your `STRef`s in a list which means that you'll have to traverse `O(n)` steps for every lookup and modification. This can be alleviated  by using something like `Data.Map.Map` which has `O(log(n))` lookup and modification time.

You could also use a mutable `Array` or `Vector` for `O(1)` lookup/modification time in the `ST` monad. This is probably the fastest method.

Comment: I have tried to use MVectors. It did improve the timing on my other test cases by 30%, but still not fast enough for the last one.

Comment: It worked. I simply used non-parsed strings for the Map keys, like "0" "1" .. "99". It made the whole thing run 7 times faster.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think of that! `String` is almost always going to be a bottleneck. If you want fast parsing, take a look at `attoparsec` over `bytestring`.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done as a one-liner using [`accumArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v%3aaccumArray) from `Data.Array`. Something like `accumArray (+) 0 (0,99) . zip values $ repeat 1` where `values` is the input.

It appears to still not be fast enough, which is somewhat vexing. `accumArray` is more or less as efficient as possible for what it does. Testing on my system reveals the time for processing 1,000,000 input values to be about 1 second, even without compiling it, and that time is dominated by generating the random inputs. That's a far cry from the 5 seconds on the test site.. I have to wonder how overloaded that system is.